# View not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am  new to Laravel, I am getting this error

> View [admin.users.show] not found.

when I try to visit edit file in the views admin users folder.

My route looks like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('/admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
```

My route list looks like this;

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                       |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | POST      | admin/users             | users.store      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@store                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users             | users.index      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@index                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/create      | users.create     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@create                       | web          |
|        | DELETE    | admin/users/{user}      | users.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@destroy                      | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/users/{user}      | users.update     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@update                       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}      | users.show       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@show                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}/edit | users.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@edit                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                    | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | login                   |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                   | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                  | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email          | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset          | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset          | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}  | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+'''
```

From the image, the file edit exists but I am not able to figure out why there is an error
[image: From the image, the file edit exists but I am not able to figure out why there is an error]

my controller;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\UsersRequest;
use App\Photo;
use App\Role;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AdminUsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $users=User::paginate(10);
        return view('admin.users.index',  compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        $role=Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

        return view('admin.users.create', compact('role'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(UsersRequest $request)
    {
        //
       $input =$request->all();
       if($file=$request->file('photo_id')) {
           $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
           $file->move('images', $name);
           $photo = Photo::create(['path' => $name]);
           $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;

       }
       $input['password']= bcrypt($request->password);
       User::create($input);

       return redirect('/Admin/users');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        return view('admin.users.show');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $user=User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        return view('admin.users.update');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        return view('admin.users.delete');
    }

    public function authors(){
        //
        return view('admin.users.authors');
    }
}
```

Why is `mysite/admin/users/edit` calling for show.blade.php instead of edit.blade.php

Comment: Reformat the code and share your controller as well

Comment: `admin.users.show` means there should be a `resources/views/admin/users/show.blade.php` file. No matching file is seen in your directory listing.

Comment: Clear the laravel cache and it should fix the problem

Comment: Can you show us `edit.blade.php`? @Tula

Answer (score 1):

The error you shared says that the missing view is **"show"** not **"edit"**.
If you create the view **"admin/users/show.blade.php"** the error will be solved

Comment: Yes, I don,t have show.blade.php, This error comes up when I type this url in my browser: mywebsite/admin/users/edit and the file edit.blade.php exists!

Answer (score 0):

> This error comes up when I type this url in my browser: mywebsite/admin/users/edit and the file edit.blade.php exists!

The issue there is your edit route is `admin/users/{user}/edit`, not `admin/users/edit`. Going to `admin/users/edit` is going to the **show** route, and attempting to look up a user with an ID of "edit". You need to be going to a URL like `admin/users/1/edit`, where 1 is the ID of the user you want to show.